# Add a Build Pipeline to an existing branch

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

In Azure Devops, when i view a branch `Repos->Branches->Select a branch` i was able to click **Set up build**.
However, i am not able to choose an existing pipeline there.

When i select a pipeline `Pipeline->Edit->Triggers` i can add **Branch filters** aswell as **path filters**, however those do not take effect.

I tried to add filters for `release/my-release` aswell as `release/*` or a path-filter `release`.

I want to be able to start a pipeline from the Branch overview. What do i have to do?

Comment: Are you using YAML or Classic pipelines?

Comment: Hi @efkah, does the answer below resolve you puzzle and meet your requirement? If yes, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using YAML pipelines, e.g. azure-pipeline.yml, make sure this file is also available in your branch.

If the pipeline YAML was added to `main` after you've branched the `release` branches, the build will never trigger. Because the branch doesn't have the pipeline YAML .

Furthermore the triggers of the YAML should be specified in the YAML instead of `Pipeline->Edit->Triggers`.

Example:

```yaml
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - master
        - release/*
```

Don't forget to **turn off** the "Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here" Option:
[image: Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here ON must be OFF]